# Writing in the middle of row

Tags: tables

I am trying to make a table like the attached picture. I need the challenges to be in the middle, as in the picture. How can I do that?

[image]

```
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{ |p{10cm}|p{4cm}|  }
\hline
col1 & col2  \\

\hline

•   ssssss\par

•   ssssss\par

•   sssss \par

•   sssss\par

&•  No standard datasets \par • Data accuracy and recency   O2\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\caption{}
    \label{fig:Resobj}
    \end{table}
```

Comment: To help you search better, this is the "vertical alignment" of the item.  And this has nothing to do with overleaf.

Comment: If you mean horizontal centering, then `col1 & \hfil col2`, where `\hfil` has been added.

Comment: Try replacing the `p`column types with the `m` column types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if the following solution works for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabitem}{itemize}{1}% <-- defined new list
\setlist[tabitem]{parsep = 0.25ex,
                  leftmargin = *,
                  label = $\bullet$,
                  before = \vspace{-1ex},
                  after = \vspace{-\baselineskip}
                  }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{|m{10cm}|m{4cm}|}
    \hline
col1 & col2  \\
    \hline
    \begin{tabitem}
\item   ssssss
\item   ssssss
\item   sssss 
\item   sssss
    \end{tabitem}   &   \begin{tabitem}
                    \item   No standard datasets
                    \item   Data accuracy and recency   O2
                        \end{tabitem}   \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
    \label{fig:Resobj}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, that worked for me :)